# How can I target the child of the second element jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I target the child of the second element with jQuery:

```
<div class="item active"></div>
<div class="item active">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="item active"></div>
<div class="item active"></div>
```

I tried these:

```
$(".item .active:nth-child(2) .overlay").addClass("test");
$(".item .active:nth-child(2)").find("overlay").addClass("test");
```

But none worked.

What did I do wrong, how can I target it?

Comment: Your formatting is wrong. Remove the space between item and active.

$(".item.active:nth-child(2) .overlay").addClass("test");
$(".item.active:nth-child(2)").find("overlay").addClass("test");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove space between *.item* and *.active*

```
$(".item.active:nth-child(2) .overlay").addClass("test");
$(".item.active:nth-child(2)").find("overlay").addClass("test");
```

then both of them work fine

see my code : https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/jwBpZo